# String array of n dimensions - c

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to know how to create a dynamic array of 2 strings per array. And I'm not sure how. I know how to create an array of strings, but not one of "n" dimensions, and i want to know how.

Here are some parts of my code, which is just currently an array of strings:

First I declared my array inside an struct:

```
typedef struct{
   char bloqueCedula[7];
   short bloqueDia;
   char **bloqueLibrosPrestados;//This is the array i want to modify
}RegistroControl;
```

then I initialize it on my first registration:

```
void primerRegistro(RegistroArchivo regArch, RegistroControl *regControl) {

    strcpy(regControl->bloqueCedula, regArch.cedula);
    regControl->bloqueDia = regArch.dia;
    regControl->bloqueLibrosPrestados = malloc(cont * sizeof(regControl->bloqueLibrosPrestados));
    regControl->bloqueLibrosPrestados[0] = malloc(7 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(regControl->bloqueLibrosPrestados[0], regArch.codigoLibro);
    imprimirCabecera();
    //printf("%s\n", regControl->bloqueLibrosPrestados[cont-1]);
}
```

In the code above I made each string of a length 7, because I already know the length of what I need to copy on it, which is 6.

This is how I kept making it grow:

```
void procesarRegistro(RegistroArchivo regArch, RegistroControl *regControl) {
    cont++;
    regControl->bloqueLibrosPrestados = realloc(regControl->bloqueLibrosPrestados,cont * sizeof(regControl->bloqueLibrosPrestados));
    regControl->bloqueLibrosPrestados[cont-1] = malloc(7 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(regControl->bloqueLibrosPrestados[cont-1], regArch.codigoLibro);
    printf("%s\n", regControl->bloqueLibrosPrestados[cont-2]);
}
```

I want to know how to add another string of 2 length next to the one that is 7 length.  This codes are parts of a code that reads from a file until it reaches EOF, that's why I used a counter which is "cont".

Comment: `wanna` = `want to`

Comment: Yes...sorry...I was writting the way I speak...

Comment: How many dimensions is **n** dimensions? In C you must pretty much decide how much is **n**?

Comment: In this case just 2...but I would be happy to know how to make of n dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `char**`.

Suppose `a`. Allocate some memory to `a`.

```
a= malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
if( a == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s","error in malloc");
    exit(1);
}
```

Now for each of the position of `a` you do the same thing only this time it is for `char`.

```
a[i]= malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
if( a[i] == NULL)
{
   //...

}
```

Free them when done.

```
free(a[i]); //for each i.
free(a);
a=NULL;
```

**Now this is 2 dimension**

Now I don't know when you need more than this. This can always be extended.

`char *** aa;` But it is not needed. [<sup>{read this}</sup>](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

If you need it then you should think over your data representation.

#### Theoretical idea for N dimensional strings

For n dimensional you can do this:-

```
char **...n...** complicated= malloc(sizeof(char**...n...>**)*N1);
// malloc check
for(int i=0;i<N1;i++)
  complicated[i]= malloc(sizeof(char**...(n-1)...**)*N2);

...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: If you find [three stars](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) somewhere, there's **always** a better way to write this code without them.

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: Yep...that's what I mant..I read the article before.. Forgot to refer.

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: I am wondering the same..why would somebody need that. You can suggest something for the answer if you feel like.(Some modifications)

Comment: Will it be the same process if I want to add another string? I wanna create a char ***array, and have two strings per row. One string of 7 length, and the other of 2

Comment: Yes then you will allocate differently . For example...you need one of length 2 and one of 7. Then `array[i][j]=malloc(7*sizeof(char))` and `array[i][j+1]=malloc(2*sizeof(char))` @user8863098

Comment: How? I'm new here haha